# Get condition of WHERE clause from table

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have `table1` which has only 2 columns: `id` and `condition`. For example:

```
id    condition
--------------------
100   caption LIKE "%xyz%"
200   tag=5
300   color>153
...
```

The user sends an id to the server, and a specific select query must be run on `table2` based on the condition of that id. For example, if id 100 is sent to server, then this query must be run:

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE caption LIKE "%xyz%"
```

How to get the condition from table1 and run the query with that condition? I have already tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 AS t1 ON t1.id=... WHERE t1.condition
```

However, I get the following warning with no result.

> Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'caption LIKE "%xyz%"'

Comment: How do you interact with the SQL, such as with PHP or something?

Comment: @Martin with PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't particularly recommend storing SQL code as you are describing.

But you have a client and a server.  The solution is simply to query `table1` for the condition and then construct the query that you want from that.  This requires two queries.

You could set up a stored procedure inside the database that uses dynamic SQL for the same purpose.

There are several reasons why this is not desirable:

- The code can introduce syntax errors which are quite hard to debug.
- The code is subject to SQL injection, depending on the security features around `table1`.
- Changes to the underlying tables might invalidate the conditions.

What is an alternative? One possibility is to create separate views for the different conditions.  Or, just create one query and pass in parameters:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where (caption like :caption or :caption is null) and
      (tag = :tag or :tag is null) and 
      (color > :color or :color is null);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is possible in `MySQL 5+` using prepared statements. You can create a procedure with a condition id as an argument:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE get_from_table2_by_condition_id(IN conditionId bigint)
BEGIN
    SET @condition = NULL;

    SELECT cond
    INTO @condition
    FROM table1
    WHERE id = conditionId;
    
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE ', COALESCE(@condition, 'FALSE'));
    
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END//

DELIMITER ;

CALL get_from_table2_by_condition_id(100);
```

See a working example in this [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sD8Udgd8cNYBYU2teP9WLE/0)

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible, and if it where possible that would be a huge stored SQL injection security hole. To be able to do this, you will need something that will parse the stored condition and evaluate the condition on the fly. As far as I'm aware, MySQL has nothing built in for this.